# install4j - Click on Hyperlink, the web browser doesn't open

Tags: linux, hyperlink, install4j

In **linux**, I install the application in **root mode**.
At the end of installation, I have a **hyperlink**, but when I click on the link, the WebBrowser doesn't open and I see an error in the console:

"GConf-WARNING **: Client failed to connect to the D-BUS daemon:
Did not receive a reply. Possible causes include: the remote application did not send a reply, the message bus security policy blocked the reply, the reply timeout expired, or the network connection was broken.
Erreur GConf : Aucun service D-BUS en cours d'exécution"

What is wrong in my installer ? Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

This means that java.awt.Desktop#browse does not work on your system.

Answer (score 1):

I'm having the same problem.  I then tried a bit of code:

```
Desktop d = Desktop.getDesktop();
System.out.println(d.isSupported(Desktop.Action.BROWSE));
d.browse(new URI("http://www.qoppa.com"));
```

and it returned true for isSupported() and opened the browser without any errors.

We're using install4j 6.0.3 and we see the problem in Debian 8.2 with MATE