# install4j - click hyperlink and browser doesn't open in Linux

Tags: linux, hyperlink, install4j

I'm using install4j v10.0.1, Java 11, and Ubuntu 20.04.  I have a multi-line HTML label with some text and an href link to a website.  The hyperlink works when running the installer in Windows environments, but fails with the following error message in Linux environments:  **"An error occurred while starting the browser."**

This issue seems to be the same as reported in [install4j - Click on Hyperlink, the web browser doesn't open](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29510250/install4j-click-on-hyperlink-the-web-browser-doesnt-open).

After reading the other post, I wrote similar code to test Desktop.isSupported(Desktop.Action.BROWSE).  It returns "true" in my Linux environment, but the browser still does not open successfully when I click on any hyperlinks in the installer.  Any suggestions for how to get install4j hyperlinks working in Linux would be appreciated.

Comment: This is indeed the same question as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29510250/install4j-click-on-hyperlink-the-web-browser-doesnt-open. If Desktop.browse does not work on a Linux system, install4j has no way of opening the browser.

Comment: Desktop.browse does work (return "true") in my Linux environment.  I created a simple Java program to test it.  That's why I created this post, because the Linux environment I'm testing intall4j in seems like it should support hyperlinks in install4j.  As a workaround to hyperlinks not working, is there a way to make text in the installer selectable for copy/paste?

Comment: If Desktop.browse returns true and the browser is not shown, install4j cannot fix this problem. You can make text selectable by using a text form component set its "Initialization script" property to `configurationObject.setEditable(false);`

Comment: Thanks for the quick response and advice.  The text form components don't seem to support HTML and hyperlinks, but I found the "HTML or text display" form component fits my use case.  Is there a way to access the configurationObject from a "HTML or text display" form component, so I can do things like set the background color and remove the border on that component?

Comment: You should use the ""Multi-line HTML label" form component" instead. It has no scroll pane border and a configurationObject of type JTextPane on which you can set the background.

Comment: I was originally using a "Multi-line HTML label", but the issue with that form component is the text is not selectable for copy/paste.  In case users run into the issue of the browser not being able to open automatically, we want them to be able to copy/paste the URL from the text into a browser window the user has already opened.  Experimenting with different form components lead me to the "HTML or text display" component...it supports HTML and the text is selectable for copy/paste...but it doesn't look as nice as the Multi-line HTML label component.

Comment: Please contact support@ej-technologies.com to get a pre-release version where the configuration object of the "HTML or text display" form component  is exposed as a JTextPane.

Comment: You can set the initialization script property of the "Multi-line HTML label" to `configurationObject.setFocusable(true);
configurationObject.setRequestFocusEnabled(true);` to make text selectable. We'll add this as a property in the next feature release.

Comment: Thank you, Ingo!  Using those configurationObject settings in the "Multi-line HTML label" initialization script made all of the text selectable for copy/paste.